# How to accept keyboard input alongside input from JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling, keyboard-events

I created a calculator to help me practice GUI creation, since I'm new at it. It works perfectly thus far. The user clicks on the button for the corresponding number/operation that they desire. However I would like to add another feature which allows the user to use their keyboard as an optional source of input. From looking at KeyListener examples, it seems like that could be helpful...but I can't come up with a straightforward way of using it to accomplish my idea.

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame {

private ArrayList<JButton> numbers;   // holds numerical buttons
private ArrayList<JButton> operations; // holds math operation buttons
private ArrayList<JButton> aux;      // holds equals, clear and delete buttons

private JTextField answerField;   // text field which displays current operands/answer

// panels for numerical,  math operation and auxillary buttons
private JPanel numberPanel, functionPanel, answerPanel;

private double op1, op2;  // numerical value of each operand
private String op1Str, op2Str; // current String value of each operand
private String operation;  // current math operation

// true if value is set, false if not
private boolean op1HasValue, op2HasValue, operationHasValue;

private String answer;   // holds current equation

public Calculator()
{
    super("Java Calculator");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

    op1HasValue = op2HasValue = operationHasValue = false;
    answer = "";
    op1Str = "";
    op2Str = "";

    //create panels
    numberPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    functionPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    answerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    //add number buttons to panel
    numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        numbers.add(new JButton("" + i));
        numberPanel.add(numbers.get(i));
    }
    // also add decimal point button
    numbers.add(new JButton("."));
    numberPanel.add(numbers.get(10));

    // add function buttons to panel
    operations = new ArrayList<>();
    operations.add(new JButton("+"));
    operations.add(new JButton("-"));
    operations.add(new JButton("*"));
    operations.add(new JButton("/"));

    for(JButton button: operations)    
        functionPanel.add(button);


    // add auxillary buttons to panel
    aux = new ArrayList<>();
    aux.add(new JButton("\u21D0"));
    aux.add(new JButton("Clr"));
    aux.add(new JButton("="));

    for(JButton button: aux)    
        functionPanel.add(button);


    // add text field to panel
    answerField = new JTextField(15);
    answerField.setEditable(false);
    answerPanel.add(answerField);

    add(numberPanel);
    add(functionPanel);
    add(answerPanel);

    // add button listeners
    myHandler handler = new myHandler();

    for(JButton button: numbers)
        button.addActionListener(handler);

    for(JButton button: operations)
        button.addActionListener(handler);

    for(JButton button: aux)
        button.addActionListener(handler);

}

private class myHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if((event.getActionCommand()).equals("Clr"))
        {
            op1HasValue = op2HasValue = operationHasValue = false;
            op1Str = "";
            op2Str = "";
            operation = "";
            answer = "";
            answerField.setText("");
        }
        else if((event.getActionCommand()).equals("\u21D0"))
        {
            if(!operationHasValue)
            {
                if(!op1Str.isEmpty())
                {
                    op1Str = op1Str.substring(0, op1Str.length() - 1);
                    answer = answer.substring(0, answer.length() - 1);
                    if(op1Str.isEmpty())
                        op1HasValue = false;
                    answerField.setText(answer);
                }
            }
            else if(operationHasValue && !op2HasValue)
            {
                operation = "";
                operationHasValue = false;
                answer = answer.substring(0, answer.length() - 3);
                answerField.setText(answer);
            }
            else
            {
                op2Str = op2Str.substring(0, op2Str.length() - 1);
                answer = answer.substring(0, answer.length() - 1);
                    if(op2Str.isEmpty())
                        op2HasValue = false;
                answerField.setText(answer);
            }
        }  // wait for integer input event, add integer to operand #1
        else if((!op1HasValue || !operationHasValue) && (numbers.contains((JButton)event.getSource())))
        {
            answer = answer + event.getActionCommand();
            answerField.setText(answer);
            op1Str = op1Str + event.getActionCommand();
            op1HasValue = true;
        }   // wait for operation input event, save operand #1
        else if(!operationHasValue && op1HasValue && operations.contains((JButton)event.getSource()))
        {
            op1 = Double.parseDouble(op1Str);
            answerField.setText(answer + " " + event.getActionCommand() + " ");
            answer = answer + " " + event.getActionCommand() + " ";
            operation = event.getActionCommand();
            operationHasValue = true;
        }   // wait for integer input event, add integer to operand #2
        else if(operationHasValue && numbers.contains((JButton)event.getSource()))
        {
            answer = answer + event.getActionCommand();
            answerField.setText(answer);
            op2Str = op2Str + event.getActionCommand();
            op2HasValue = true;
        }  // wait for equals sign input event, save operand #2, calculate answer
        else if(op1HasValue && op2HasValue && operationHasValue && (event.getActionCommand()).equals("="))
        {
            op2 = Double.parseDouble(op2Str);

            if(operation.equals("+"))
                answerField.setText("" + (op1 + op2));
            else if(operation.equals("-"))
                answerField.setText("" + (op1 - op2));
            else if(operation.equals("*"))
                answerField.setText("" + (op1 * op2));
            else if(operation.equals("/"))
                answerField.setText("" + (op1 / op2));

            answer = "";
            op1HasValue = op2HasValue = operationHasValue = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `KeyListener`, it's a better idea to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), especially if you're working with Swing. Following the tutorial's example, you might try something like this (i.e. if the user pushed the 1 key):

```
functionPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
    .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("1"),"1 key");

functionPanel.getActionMap().put("1 key",new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        // perform operation here
    }
});
```

Here's a better example, since you can see what you should put in the `actionPerformed` method(i.e. if the user pressed the C key for clear):

```
InputMap inMap = functionPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("C"),"Clear");

ActionMap actMap = functionPanel.getActionMap();
actMap.put("Clear",new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        op1HasValue = op2HasValue = operationHasValue = false;
        op1Str = "";
        op2Str = "";
        operation = "";
        answer = "";
        answerField.setText("");
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if you would rather use `KeyListener`, you might consider creating a new class that implements `KeyListener`, as follows. You have to realize that it will only work if the specified component has focus, which, among a few other things, is a disadvantage of using `KeyListener` as opposed to key bindings.

```
KeyHandler keyHandler = new KeyHandler();
functionPanel.addKeyListener(keyHandler);

private class KeyHandler implements KeyListener {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) /* C for clear */ {
            op1HasValue = op2HasValue = operationHasValue = false;
            op1Str = "";
            op2Str = "";
            operation = "";
            answer = "";
            answerField.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ev) {}

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ev) {}
}
```

Comment: I actually attempted something similar to your KeyHander class, but as you said, there was an issue with the component that had focus because I couldn't get an event to occur. I'll do further research and learn a bit more about key binding, input maps and action maps. Thank you.

Comment: :) I just realized that JButtons have a doClick method. Which means once I determine if a valid key was pressed, I should only have to use the doClick method of the corresponding button. This option would prevent me from having to copy and paste from my ActionListener class and shorten the program.

Answer (score 2):

> From looking at KeyListener examples, it seems like that could be helpful...

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`. Check out this different [Key Binding](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) link which shows all the Key Bindings used for existing Swing components.

> add another feature which allows the user to use their keyboard as an optional source of input.

Using `Key Bindings` you can create a simple `Action` to be used to enter numbers:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class CalculatorPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JTextField display;

    public CalculatorPanel()
    {
        Action numberAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                display.setCaretPosition( display.getDocument().getLength() );
                display.replaceSelection(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        display = new JTextField();
        display.setEditable( false );
        display.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            String text = String.valueOf(i);
            JButton button = new JButton( text );
            button.addActionListener( numberAction );
            button.setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.BLACK) );
            button.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(50, 50) );
            buttonPanel.add( button );

            InputMap inputMap = button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(text), text);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD" + text), text);
            button.getActionMap().put(text, numberAction);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
//      UIManager.put("Button.margin", new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( new CalculatorPanel() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Of course you will need to create separate Actions for each of your arithmetic functions.